# Optimum Bluetooth range - is there an optimum minimum distance?

Tags: bluetooth

In the past when I've been struggling to get Bluetooth devices to connect, I've tried to maximise their chances of making friends with each other by physically touching them together. I've generally assumed that the optimum range is as small as possible.

However, I've heard a claim that that there is an ideal minimum distance that devices work better with (I'm not sure I recall the claimed distance, but maybe it was on the order of about 10cm).

I can't find any information about this and I don't know of any physical effect that would cause this. Maybe some sort of echo effect or a result of getting more power than is expected? Is this claim plausible?